# Что и зачем класс Variable PyTorch?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch

Читая неплохую [статью о PyTorch](https://neurohive.io/ru/tutorial/glubokoe-obuchenie-s-pytorch/)
обнаружил такое:

```
x = Variable(torch.ones(2, 2) * 2, requires_grad=True)
```

В статье не говорилось, но без предваряющего кода:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
```

Оно не работало.  Я не понял зачем этот класс нужен и в чем его отличие от **Tensor**.
Вот что говорит help():

```
help(Variable)
Help on class Variable in module torch.autograd.variable:

class Variable(torch._C._LegacyVariableBase)
 |  # mypy doesn't understand torch._six.with_metaclass
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Variable
 |      torch._C._LegacyVariableBase
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Static methods inherited from torch._C._LegacyVariableBase:
 |  
 |  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
 |      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
```

Ну легче не стало...

Вот код с использованием *Variable*:

```
import torch

from torch.autograd import Variable
x = Variable(torch.ones(2, 2) * 2, requires_grad=True)

z = 2 * (x * x) + 5 * x
z.backward(torch.ones(2, 2))
print(x.grad)
tensor([[13., 13.],
        [13., 13.]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перейдя по [ссылке](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated), можно узнать, что Variable API is deprecated!
То есть теперь тензора с (requires_grad=True) обладают магией прежних Variable ))

Грубо говоря - Variable устарели ввиду оснащения обычных ***torch.Tensor*** всей мощью  ***Variable***.  Однако код с его использованием по-прежнему работает.

Comment: По-моему стоит отметить данный ответ как верный)

Comment: @MaxU  - только по вашей просьбе!

Answer (score 3):

`Variable` это надстройка над `Tensor`, которая позволяет подсчитывать градиенты для обратного распространения ошибки.

Из указанной в вопросе ссылки:

> **Автоматическое дифференцирование в PyTorch**

> В библиотеках глубокого обучения есть механизмы вычисления градиента ошибки и обратного распространения ошибки через вычислительный граф. Этот механизм, называемый автоградиентом в PyTorch, легко доступен и интуитивно понятен. Переменный класс — главный компонент автоградиентной системы в PyTorch. Переменный класс обертывает тензор и позволяет автоматически вычислять градиент на тензоре при вызове функции `.backward()`. Объект содержит данные из тензора, градиент тензора (единожды посчитанный по отношению к некоторому другому значению, потеря) и содержит также ссылку на любую функцию, созданную переменной (если это функция созданная пользователем, ссылка будет пустой).

Очевидно кто-то перевел `Variable` как `Переменный класс`. ;)

P.S. [здесь можно найти ответы на этот вопрос на английском](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-tensors-and-variables-in-pytorch/4914/4)

P.P.S. лучше стараться читать туториалы в оригинале, тогда не будет возникать "проблем перевода", как выше.

Comment: Я заменял в коде примеров на Variable  на torch.Tensor и все работало. Потому и спросил.
Приведу пример кода  -  расширю вопрос

Comment: А можно вопрос?
Вот в этой книге  "Знакомство с PyTorch. Брайан Макмахан Делип Рао"  Variable  не встречается ни разу.  Это я плохую книгу начал читать?  Или без   Variable  можно таки обойтись?